# QTextOption::alignment drops information

Tags: qt, qt5

Why can't [`QTextOption`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextoption.html) store the `Qt::AlignBaseline` flag?
After some research I found that it is stored in a 8-bit wide bit field in QTextOption. Since it has the value `0x100`, it's no surprise that the flag is dropped.

**Is this behavior intended?** I didn't yet find out what [`Qt::AlignBaseline`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum) exactly does, however, according to docs, it is a pretty ordinary vertical alignment flag

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextOption>

struct MyTextOption
{
    int int_alignment : 8;
    Qt::Alignment alignment;
};

int main()
{
    const Qt::Alignment alignment = Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignBaseline;
    qDebug() << alignment;            // Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignBaseline

    QTextOption option;
    option.setAlignment(alignment);
    qDebug() << option.alignment();   // Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignLeading

    MyTextOption my_option;
    my_option.int_alignment = alignment;
    qDebug() << static_cast<Qt::Alignment>(my_option.int_alignment);
                                      // Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignLeading

    my_option.alignment = alignment;
    qDebug() << my_option.alignment;  // Qt::AlignLeft|Qt::AlignBaseline
}
```

I'm using Qt 5.12.

Comment: Reproducible on Qt 5.11.

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74652